# NSTableView reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes:) breaks autolayout

Tags: macos, autolayout, nstableview, appkit

I have an NSTableView that can swap in different cell views based on data values for the row. When the model changes, I reload the table, and the table's delegate will provide the right table cell view for the new data.

The table uses autolayout for its cell views. All cell views load normally initially. When updating the table after a model change, I get different results depending on whether I call `reloadData()` or `reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes)`. When using `reloadData()`, the cell view is loaded and autolayout works fine. If I use `reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes)`, autolayout produces completely different, unexpected results.

I created a sample project to demonstrate the problem. 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaS2P.png) is an image of the project setup including constraints set on the table cell views. There are two row templates, one with a blue view (even rows), one with green (odd rows) that should span the table width (minus a bit of padding). A controller supplies the cell views:

```
class TableController: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    var colorData = [1, 0, 1, 0]

    @IBAction func swapLine(_ sender: Any) {
        colorData[1] = (colorData[1] + 1) % 2
    //        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: [1], columnIndexes: [0])
    }
}

extension TableController: NSTableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return colorData.count
    }
}

extension TableController: NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let cellId = (colorData[row]) % 2 == 0 ? "EvenCell" : "OddCell"
        return tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(cellId), owner: self)
    }
}
```

A button in the interface just swaps the data for row 1 and reloads the data. The initial view looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKGwY.png) (alternating green and blue rects). If you use `reloadData()`, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxS62.png) (row 1 changed from blue to green). But, if you use `reloadData(withRowIndexes:columnIndexes:)`, the cell view shrinks to 40 points wide vice 480 as in the others. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbbeB.jpg) a grab of the view debugger showing the cell view with the wrong size and showing ambiguous width constraints (this doesn't happen when using `reloadData()`).

The documentation mentions that the row view is reused with `reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes:)`, but not with `reloadData()`, which I've verified. I imagine this reusing of the row view is what's causing the autolayout problems, but I can find no connection. Nothing found at SO, AppKit release notes, WWDC videos, Google searches or from pounding my head on the table. Would be truly grateful for assistance.

**Update:**
Here's the code for ColorView:

```
class ColorView: NSView {
    @IBInspectable var intrinsicHeight: CGFloat = 20
    @IBInspectable var color: NSColor = NSColor.blue

    override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
        return NSSize(width: NSView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: intrinsicHeight)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        color.setFill()
        dirtyRect.fill()
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the classes of Custom View and Color View? Did you replace the `NSTableCellView` by a `NSView`?

Comment: The table cell view is just an NSView. I updated the question with the code for ColorView--just a simple subclass with an intrinsic height and background color.

Comment: Try a cell view of (a subclass of) class `NSTableCellView` and/or a cell view with the same `autoresizingMask` as the default cell view.

Comment: Thanks, @Willeke. I gave it a shot, but there's no change

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Here's my code: https://github.com/nyousefi/Tables

Comment: Thanks @NimaYousefi. I noticed your version isn't using autolayout for the table. If you change the ColorView's intrinsicHeight to something different than what's in IB, the cells don't self-size. Try switching the table view's RowSizeStyle to Automatic (Auto Layout) and choose different values for the ColorView's intrinsicHeight. You should see my issue.

Comment: I see it now. Two observations: 1) You should provide a width for the intrinsicContentSize based on the contents of the view. For what you've presented, I'm not sure you need to be using intrinsicContentSize. 2) The swapping of the views is causing ColorView's drawRect method to be called with different dirtyRect values. The initial table load is actually the one that's wrong because it doesn't use intrinsicContentSize. When you swap, the dirtyRect.bounds == intrinsicContentSize. This is confusing and strikes me as a bug on Apple part.

Comment: I think you're probably on the right track, @NimaYousefi, but the actual control that ColorView is simulating is a custom text view whose height depends on its width. I really want it to be the full length of the table row (minus padding) so that the height can be determined based on that width. If the control doesn't use intrinsic height, I'd have to go back to manually manipulating frames. I could do it, but I want me some autolayout magic! :)

Comment: You can still use autolayout, but instead of using intrinsicContentSize you'd use the NSTableViewDelegate method `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat`. You can calculate the width based on the bounds of the tableView, and then calculate the row height of your text using that width. Use autolayout on the textView so it scales with the row height. That's the approach I've taken in our apps and it works pretty well. The height math is the hardest part, but you'll have to deal with that regardless of approach.

Comment: What you've suggested is a completely reasonable approach. To lay out the text view, I could set its width to the width of the row, calculate the height, and pass that to the table view. There are also approaches using a single cell view and swapping in/out subviews to support the current data. The question I'm trying to answer is why the approach I described doesn't work. If it's a bug, I'll file a radar. If it's a misunderstanding of how autolayout works, this could help me and others with an edge case that isn't well documented. That said, post your answer and I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: @smr I'm running into this same problem. Did you ever find a way to get it to work while still relying on auto layout? I find if I just fully reload my entire table (`tableView.reloadData()`), the views render properly, but I lose out on the row change animations (inserting, removing, and reloading).

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it working. If I call `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()` on the cell just before it is returned (so that all its subviews like the dynamic text are already set), then it seems to work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
  //...

  cell.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
  return cell
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm... further testing shows this helps some, but it doesn't always work. Dang.

Comment: For what it’s worth, Apple has acknowledged this as a bug. I’ll try to update when they close the radar

Comment: Hitting the same, I'm losing a width constraint on NSTextFields (they just deactivate, falling back to intrinsicSize) when doing this. Resorted to removeRows, insertRows ...
Neither the `addSubview` nor the `layoutSubtree` workaround presented seem to work for me (10.14).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and noticed the actual auto-layout constraints were missing for the rows that `reloadData` is called for. My (hacky) solution was to add the constraints that are supposed to be automatically set up for the cell manually as well. Note that in my table view I'm just using one column so I'm able to set the width constraint to equal the row's width instead of relying on the columns specified width.

```
class CustomRowView: NSTableRowView {
  override func addSubview(_ view: NSView) {
    super.addSubview(view)

    // Add constraints NSTableView is supposed to set up
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
  }
}
```